# In C# a Try block, the catch section i want a exception to be thrown if in my textbock a int is entered?

Tags: c#

So if you push the enter button, and the user enters a number i want the program to throw out a exception that no integers may be entered in the text block.

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
        try
        {
            string[] words = { txtInfo.Text };

            foreach (string f in words)
            {
                lstResults.Items.Add(f);
            }
            txtInfo.Text = "";  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }   
    }
```

Very small project for school but would like to specify the exception.

Comment: Don't use try/catches to handle program logic. There's also no point in catching that exception if you're just going to throw it again.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Also, please be clear as to why you want to throw an exception, vs say outputting something to the console / UI explaining to the user what they did wrong.

Comment: Also, please update your question to show 3 examples of **valid** inputs, and three of invalid inputs (that should throw an exception).

Comment: Look at using int32.TryParse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: TryParse is my next option just wondered if there is another way.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the of the `try`-`catch` construct. Its purpose is not enabling you to throw your own exceptions, but its function is to **catch** exceptions that might have been thrown by the code within the `try` block. If all you want is to create and throw an exception based on some condition, then there is no (obvious) need for a `try`-`catch` clause...

Comment: Just thought there was a different way, but solved it through using the TryParse. Thanks every one for helping!

Comment: That will be awesome!

Comment: You could also just block numbers from being inputted at all

Comment: Just for lulz: You could for example do bit tests on a char value to determine if it is a digit or not. If bit 4 and 5 are set and bits 6 to bits 15 unset and either bit 3 unset or bit 3 set while bit 1 and 2 unset, then the char is a digit ;-) (the LSB is bit 0, the MSB is bit 15)

Comment: Another pointless way to do it: You could embed the text into a json string as an unquoted value of a property of a json object. Then try to deserialize this json string into an object of a (custom) type that has a corresponding int property/field (using the popular Newtonsoft.Json de/serializer, for example). If deserialization is successful, the text was an integer. If deserialization fails, the text was not an integer... ;-P

Comment: This `string[] words = { txtInfo.Text };` does not split the text into words. Use this instead: `string[] words = txtInfo.Text.Split();`

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is to implement Guard Clauses. Guard Clause is just a simple checking of the input parameters at the top of your method.

I would totally remove try catch from your code and just check if the text in the box is an integer.

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        //this will check if the text from the box can be parsed as an integer then
        //exit this method but show message box with your message.      
        if(int.TryParse(txtInfo.Text, out var test)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Integers are not allowed");
             return; 
          }
            string[] words = { txtInfo.Text };

            foreach (string f in words)
            {
                lstResults.Items.Add(f);
            }
            txtInfo.Text = "";  

    }
```

I hope this helps.